# Custom vue directive to render only if present

Tags: vue.js

Frequently, I want to render a div (or other element) only if it has content. This means repeating the reference to the content in the tag, and in v-if, like this...

```
<div v-if="store.sometimesIWillBeEmpty">{{store.sometimesIWillBeEmpty}}</div>
```

With custom directives, I want to create a directive, v-fill, that behaves just like the code above, but with simplified syntax...

```
<div v-fill="store.sometimesIWillBeEmpty"></div>
```

**updated** The following works when message is not empty. What do I set or clear to render nothing when message is empty?

```
var store = {message: "hello cobber"}
Vue.directive('fill', 
  function (el, binding, vnode) {
    if(binding.value)
      el.innerHTML = binding.value
    else
      el = null
  }
);

new Vue({
  el: '#fill-example',
  data: {
    store: store
  }
})
```

I'm one line away. [Here's my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/t0b4140t/1/) Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Don't `eval(binding.expression)`; use `binding.value`.

Comment: Ok I was closer than I thought. Works like a charm. Would you like to put that in an answer for some stack dollars?

Comment: update: not totally working. I've updated the code and the question. The `else` part is causing me problems.

Comment: why not do `el.innerHTML = null` after else?

Comment: Nice try, but no. The point is to try and get the containing element to disappear if there's no content. If I do el.outerHTML = "", I can get rid of my element, but then it doesn't come back if message reappears.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make a straightforward component to do what you want. A directive requires a bit more manipulation to be able to remove the element and put it back in the right place.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#fill-example',
  data: {
    empty: '',
    notEmpty: 'I have content'
  },
  components: {
    renderMaybe: {
      props: ['value'],
      template: `<div v-if="value" class="boxy">{{value}}</div>`
    }
  },
  directives: {
    fill: {
      bind(el, binding) {
        Vue.nextTick(() => {
          el.vFillMarkerNode = document.createComment('');
          el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.vFillMarkerNode, el.nextSibling);
          if (binding.value) {
            el.textContent = binding.value;
          } else {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
          }
        });
      },
      update(el, binding) {
        if (binding.value) {
          el.vFillMarkerNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, el.vFillMarkerNode);
          el.textContent = binding.value;
        } else {
          if (el.parentNode) {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  vm.empty = "Now I have content, too.";
}, 1500);
```

```css
.boxy {
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="fill-example">
  Components:
  <render-maybe :value="empty"></render-maybe>
  <render-maybe :value="notEmpty"></render-maybe>
  Directives:
  <div class="boxy" v-fill="empty"></div>
  <div class="boxy" v-fill="notEmpty"></div>
</div>
```